# Counter Config Element Issue

Tags: jmeter, counter, performance-testing

I have placed the counter config (DBID) element inside ForEach Controller, whatever the MatchNr value we are getting it should loop and pass the DBID_Counter value.

Issue is - i got dbid_matchNr=6, counter element is resetting its value after 3rd loop,
So i tried increasing the counter value using Beanshell(Counter1) and check its working fine, not sure why Counter Config is resetting automatically

[3rd loop--> Counter1 is 3 and dbcounter is 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrimt.png)

[4th Loop--> Counter1 is 4 and dbcounter is 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Y2N.png)

[Counter Config Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fvv9.png)

Could someone help me understand why counter element is not working as expected.?

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshots don't shed any lights on the problem you're expecting, if you're confused with the Counter behaviour be aware that you don't need it at all, since [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) exposes it's current iteration number via `${__jm__ForEach Controller__idx}` [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars)

[image]

If you want the "counter" to start from 1 you can use [__intSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum)

Also re-consider using Beanshell, [since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting